# default values and negative indexes when creating vector class

Tags: c++, vector

I decided to train myself in classes and build a `vecofint` class, that would resemble a `vector` container with several methods.

My program works great, but I have found that I do not entirely understand some principles.

**1. Default values:**

Here is my class:

```
class vecofint {
public:
    vecofint() : vec(new int[size1]) { zeros(); }
    ~vecofint() { delete vec; }
    vecofint(const int size) { set(size); vec = new int[size1]; zeros(); }
    vecofint& operator = (const vecofint& other) { vec = other.vec; size1 = other.size1; vec1 = other.vec1; }
    vecofint(const vecofint& other) : vec(other.vec), size1(other.size1), vec1(other.vec1) {}
    int getin(const int a) { return vec[a]; }
    int get() { return size1; }
    void set(const int a) { size1 = a; }
    void setin(const int a, const int val) { vec[a] = val; }
    int* pushback(const int val);
    int* pushfront(const int val);
    int* it;
    void resize(); 
    void resize1();
    void zeros() {int * i = vec; fill(i, i + size1, 0);}
    void print() { copy(vec, vec + size1, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n")); }
private:
    int size1 = 32;
    int* vec;
    int* vec1;
};
```

As you can see I assign all values of my created `vector` to 0. I do this for 2 reasons:

a) I have found that

```
vector <int> a(10);
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

prints `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`;

b) I need some default values to implement my `pushback` method:

```
int* vecofint::pushback(const int val) {
    int k = 0;
    int* it = vec;
    while (*it!=0) {
        if (k == size1) {
            resize();
            it = vec+size1/2;
        }
        ++k;
        ++it;
    }
        vec[k] = val;
        return vec;
}
```

And I use zeros. But I do not like that, because it means that I cannot use `0` as **not-default values**.

**First question:**

How can I basically avoid these assignments to zeros, but still have basic values to iterate through the `vector`? Or maybe there are other methods on how to iterate through newly created space?

2) **Negative indexes**

Suppose I am trying, by mistake, access a negative index.

**Second question:**

What my program should write in this case? Some error?

I have found that in real `vector` nothing happens, at least until a destructor is called.

Comment: 1) You don't have to fill allocated space with a default value, just maintain another field indicating the size of the space in use. 2) Negative indices are tricky, but the short answer is that the code ought to throw an exception.

Comment: Concerning your first question, I don't even know what *you* mean with "basic values" that you want to iterate through. Concerning the second question, a negative index doesn't have to be an error, see e.g. Python's handling of negative indices. They basically add the size of the sequence, so `-1` is the last, `-2` the second last etc, which comes pretty handy sometimes. However, if you want to treat this as error, you either declare it as programming error (use assert() then) or you treat it as a runtime error (throw an exception then).